# Flex item being bumped down exactly half height of previous item

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'll include an image for context, then the code:
[image: Image of flexbox I'm working with.]

The box at far right with "ABC" in it and a left/bottom border is being bumped down exactly half the height of the gradient image next to it. I know a lot of the heights/etc don't make sense, but I've removed them all and the problem persists. Any guidance here?

The HTML:

```
<div className="thing">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/75/90/?blur" alt="hey there" className="thingImage" />
  <div className="content">
    <span className="thingName">Jibber Jabb Super Long Title of a Movie or Thing Here</span><br/>
    <span className="thingRanks">
       Rank1: 1<br/>
       Rank2: 2<br/>
       Rank3: 2
    </span>
  </div>
  <div className="thingMeta">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/30/30/?blur" alt="name" className="thingIcon" />
    <span className="thingAbbrev">ABC</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

(the "className" is from React, just read it as "class" if you're not familiar with React)

The CSS:

```
.thing{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 564px;
  min-height: 68px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Helvetica", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  display: flex;
}
.thingImage{
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.thingName{
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}
.thingMeta{
  margin-left: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  height: 35px;

}
.thingAbbrev{
  border-bottom: medium solid #000000;
  border-left: medium solid #000;
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 30px;
}
.thingIcon{
  height: 30px;
}
```

The main focus of this project for me is learning React, using Flexbox is just a bonus for me here. Thanks in advance, any help or guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `thingMeta` is not a flex container (doesn't have `display: flex;`<sup>(1)</sup>), the `thingAbbrev` is not a flex item, hence the `align-self: flex-start` won't apply .

As the `img` and `span` in the `thingMeta` are normal inline elements, they align along the baseline, so i.e. adding `vertical-align: top` will align them at the top.

```css
.thing{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 564px;
  min-height: 68px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Helvetica", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  display: flex;
}
.thingImage{
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.thingName{
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}
.thingMeta{
  margin-left: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  height: 35px;
}
.thingAbbrev{
  border-bottom: medium solid #000000;
  border-left: medium solid #000;
  /* align-self: flex-start;               removed  */
  vertical-align: top;                /*   added    */
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 30px;
}
.thingIcon{
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/75/90/?blur" alt="hey there" class="thingImage" />
  <div class="content">
    <span class="thingName">Jibber Jabb Super Long Title of a Movie or Thing Here</span><br/>
    <span class="thingRanks">
       Rank1: 1<br/>
       Rank2: 2<br/>
       Rank3: 2
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="thingMeta">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/30/30/?blur" alt="name" class="thingIcon" />
    <span class="thingAbbrev">ABC</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively you can of course also simply add `display: flex` to the `thingMeta`. The downside with that is that your `img` then becomes a flex item and based on what you want to do with it, there is some cross browser issues, and many of them can be avoided by wrapping the `img` (which I didn't in below sample)

```css
.thing{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 564px;
  min-height: 68px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Helvetica", arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  display: flex;
}
.thingImage{
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.thingName{
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}
.thingMeta{
  margin-left: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;                      /*   added    */
}
.thingAbbrev{
  border-bottom: medium solid #000000;
  border-left: medium solid #000;
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 30px;
}
.thingIcon{
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/75/90/?blur" alt="hey there" class="thingImage" />
  <div class="content">
    <span class="thingName">Jibber Jabb Super Long Title of a Movie or Thing Here</span><br/>
    <span class="thingRanks">
       Rank1: 1<br/>
       Rank2: 2<br/>
       Rank3: 2
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="thingMeta">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/30/30/?blur" alt="name" class="thingIcon" />
    <span class="thingAbbrev">ABC</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> *When `display: flex` is set on an element, it is only its children that becomes flex items*

Comment: This was very helpful. I especially appreciate the effort you put into telling me why. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the below CSS and html

**CSS:**

```
.vcenter{
  display: flex;
  align-item: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Also I wrapped the `<span class="thingAbbrev">ABC</span>` in another span to get rid of an height issue due to margins.

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="thingMeta vcenter">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/30/30/?blur" alt="name" class="thingIcon" />
    <span class="vcenter"><span class="thingAbbrev">ABC</span></span>
  </div>
```

JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/ewo8bw7e/1/)